# Bind button click event from interface value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to populate the button click from interface value for example

```
interface IButton {
    buttonClickValue: string
}

export class Button implements OnInit {
     toolBar: IButton = {
       buttonClickValue: "onCML"    //I also tried this onCML()
     }
     constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {          
    }

    onCML(){    
      alert("Alert should appear on click!!!");
    }

 }
```

Here is my frontEnd button where I would like to bind the interface value to the button click

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toolBar.buttonClickValue">My Button</a>
```

However when I click on the button nothing happens I would like to see the alert. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try: `buttonClickValue: this.onCML`

Comment: @ChrisG I have tried your idea sadly it does not work but thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type for `buttonClickValue` should match the function.

```js
interface IButton {
  buttonClickValue: () => void;
}

export class Button implements OnInit {
  toolBar: IButton = {
    buttonClickValue: this.onCML,
  };
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onCML() {
    alert("Alert should appear on click!!!");
  }
}
```

Edit:
I believe you'll also need to invoke said function in the template:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toolBar.buttonClickValue()">My Button</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you it is exacly what I wanted. I can accept your anwser in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a callback type to the `buttonClickValue` property instead of `string`.
2. Assign the `onCML` callback using `this.onCML` or an arrow function. If you intend to use `this` keyword inside the callback to refer to class member variables, you either need to bind using `this.onCML.bind(this)` or use an arrow-function ([Canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/6513921)).

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

interface IButton {
  buttonClickValue: () => void;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-button",
  template: `
    <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toolBar.buttonClickValue()">
      My Button
    </a>
  `
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  toolBar: IButton = {
    buttonClickValue: () => this.onCML()
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onCML() {
    alert("Alert should appear on click!!!");
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kyb2vn?file=src/app/button.component.ts)